# "I will diminish them" Ezekiel 29:15. How was Egypt diminished by God after the Chaldean period?

Tags: history, prophecy, ezekiel, egypt

Genesis 10:13-14 NKJV

> Mizraim begot Ludim, Anamim, Lehabim, Naphtuhim,   Pathrusim, and
>   Casluhim (from whom came the Philistines and Caphtorim)

According to this passage, the ancient Egyptians existed as seven major tribes.

Ezekiel 29:13-15 NKJV

> ' Yet, thus says the Lord GOD: "At the end of forty years I will
>   gather the Egyptians from the peoples among whom they were scattered.
>
> "**I will bring back the captives of Egypt and cause them to return to
>   the land of Pathros, to the land of their origin**, and there they shall
>   be a lowly kingdom.
>
> "It shall be the lowliest of kingdoms; it shall
>   never again exalt itself above the nations, **for I will diminish them**
>   so that they will not rule over the nations anymore.

According to this passage, the origin of the ancient Egyptians is in Pathros.

Of all seven sons of Mizraim who fathered tribes called by their name, only Pathros is mentioned in the passage. Why?

1) Does it mean that Egypt would be diminished population wise (its other tribes seizing to exist) or does the word "diminish" have other connotations based on its hebrew meaning.

2) Where is Pathros located today?

Comment: For your second question as far i remember, פתרוס is probably Thebes - 560km from Cairo. It's refered also נא or נא אמון in bible.

Comment: @A.Meshu I'm not so good at reading hebrew because it doesn't have vowels. I asked about the location of Pathros because according to the prophecy, that is where the real Egyptians began. And that is where they should be currently concentrated within modern Egypt.

Comment: check out Wikipedia page on Pathros https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33185/i-will-diminish-them-ezekiel-2915-how-was-egypt-diminished-by-god-after-the